# Working with jQuery in HTML5 Blank Wordpress theme

Tags: jquery, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm having big issues trying to solve this. I'm good at `HTML` and `CSS` but it's always hard for me to work with `JS` and `jQuery`, even more when it goes inside a Wordpress theme.

So I was hoping somebody could guide me through this. The HTML5Blank theme loads a couple of JS files through functions.php by making use of the next couple of lines to load the file for custom scripts:

```
wp_register_script('html5blankscripts', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/scripts.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0'); // Custom scripts
wp_enqueue_script('html5blankscripts'); // Enqueue it!
```

And the content of that file is:

```
(function ($, root, undefined) {

    $(function () {

        'use strict';

        // DOM ready, take it away

    });

})(jQuery, this);
```

So now... what should I do to properly insert the next jQuery code in the above mentioned file?

```
$(".abc").mouseenter(function(){
    clearTimeout($('#def').data('timeoutId'));
    $('#def').show(200);
}).mouseleave(function(){
    var someElement = $(this);
    var timeoutId = setTimeout(function(){
        $('#def').hide(200);
    }, 650);
    $('#def').data('timeoutId', timeoutId); 
});

$("#def").mouseenter(function(){
    clearTimeout($('#def').data('timeoutId'));
}).mouseleave(function(){
    var someElement = $(this);
    var timeoutId = setTimeout(function(){
        $('#def').hide(200);
    }, 650);
    $('#def').data('timeoutId', timeoutId); 
});
```

I'm quite lost in this matter, so any help you can give me will be truly appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below code should do it:

```
(function ($, root, undefined) {

    $(function () {

        'use strict';

        // DOM ready, take it away
        $(".abc").mouseenter(function () {
            clearTimeout($('#def').data('timeoutId'));
            $('#def').show(200);
        }).mouseleave(function () {
            var someElement = $(this);
            var timeoutId = setTimeout(function () {
                $('#def').hide(200);
            }, 650);
            $('#def').data('timeoutId', timeoutId);
        });

        $("#def").mouseenter(function () {
            clearTimeout($('#def').data('timeoutId'));
        }).mouseleave(function () {
            var someElement = $(this);
            var timeoutId = setTimeout(function () {
                $('#def').hide(200);
            }, 650);
            $('#def').data('timeoutId', timeoutId);
        });

    });

})(jQuery, this);
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9La6yyL6/)

Comment: It worked perfectly! Thanks a lot for such a quick response :)
Would like to ask you something else. If I wanted to add multiple functions in this file, how should I do it? Oh, and also... what does the `(function ($, root, undefined)` code line do?

Comment: @RodniD Wordpress implements jQuery in a `no-conflict` mode so as not to potentially collide with other libraries that might use the `$` symbol as their namespace, hence it can only be referenced by calling `jQuery` but with that function you are essentially passing `jQuery` as a reference and `this` as the `root` you don't need the `undefined` in there AFAIK, http://digwp.com/2011/09/using-instead-of-jquery-in-wordpress/  As for adding other functions you can do so as you normally would but they won't be scoped in the `window` object so will only be accessible from the code within codeblock.

Comment: That certainly shed some light to the matter :) But how can I properly add new functions to the code above, @RobSchmuecker?

Comment: @RodniD you can put the code either inside the anonymous function if you need to reference jquery or outside if not needed. Those functions defined outside can be accessed within the `window` scope.

Comment: Think I got it now. Thanks a lot @RobSchmuecker! :)